# How to download the file by clicking the link in email by using the python script

Tags: python

I want to click on the link from email and download the file in my laptop by using python script. Any one has any idea about this?

I could see most of the information's which i am seeing in the internet is download the file in linux itself.

Comment: how about parsing the `html` source and locate the link and directly download it ?

Answer (score 0):

The Instruction to do that:

Writing a code to do the following:

1. login to your email.
2. parse your inbox and locate the specific email.
3. parse the html source and locate the url for the download link.
4. download it by connecting directly to it.